# Load bundled Javascript file as string in Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I need to load `b.js` into `a.js` as a string. The `b.js` file has require statements that need to be bundled before being loaded as a string into `a.js`.

```
// a.js

import bAsString from 'raw!./b.js';


// b.js

require('c.js');
require('d.js');
```

What currently happens is `b.js` is loaded as a string into `a.js` but it hasn't been bundled yet. The require statements still exist.

Comment: I think you will have to create separate bundles and then import them.

Comment: @RudolfOlah thanks. Using separate Webpack compilers and configs? Or is there a way to do that with entry points using just one compiler and config?

Comment: why are you trying to load b.js as a string? and I think yes you would need two different webpack configs/compilers; it's a 2-step operation.

Comment: Thats what I feared. b.js needs to be injected from a.js into a ES3 Javascript runtime dynamically. a.js is running in a CEF window.